# Binary number divisible by 3

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, logic-gates

I have do design a series circuit.
There are 3 inputs x0x1x2 which represent a 3 digit binary number.
There is one output y.
y = 1 if and only if the current number multiplied by the previous number is divisible by 3. I am supposed to use T FlipFlops.
I was thinking that I could get away by using only one FF so to remember if the previous number is divisible by 3. That way if the current number or the previous are divisible by 3 then so will their product be.

When I tried designing the tables and the states tables using only one FF the logic was too much, something like 20 gates plus the FF.
On the other hand if I use 3 FF as to rememner the whole previous number the table gets really big, like 64 rows, which I can probably reduce.

Which is the ideal solution, is there any trick or shortcut that I'm missing.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You 1FF solution seem OK too me and not that big (20 gates? I don't think so).

Comment: I think you need to clarify the idea of "Next and Previous" number. Are the numbers arriving in incrementing counting order or do the the 3 bit values arrive in a random order. It makes all the difference in how the truth table would be constructed.

Comment: all there inputs at once, then next clock cycle another three digits representing the next number

Comment: Well, with a 3-digit binary number, those only go from 0 to 7, so the number is divisible by 3 if it's 0 or 3 or 6.

Comment: See also: [Remainder of a 16-bit number divided by 3](/q/136024/remainder-of-a-16-bit-number-divided-by-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 is a prime, so only one number needs to be checked if the previous already was checked and its divisibility by 3 is stored as one bit.  There are not that many 3 bit numbers to be recognized. They are 0,3 and 6 in decimal. You must get =1 if your number is one of those. Boolean OR that with the stored divisibility.

Of course there's a trick to a beginner. How to store a bit to T-FF. With D-FF it would be simple.

**EDIT due the comments:**

Obviously someone feeds the 3 bit input number A, B and C (=ABC) and a signal G which shows that ABC is valid to be used. As long as G=1 the input ABC is assumed to be stable. That G is called normally "Strobe". It's a little different than a clock pulse. If G were a clock pulse, only G's transition edge from 0 to 1 would be the signal "ABC is valid". So let G be the strobe "ABC is valid". That G was not told to be existent in the problem text, but without it all else would be nonsense. Without G (strobe or clock pulse) there would not exist a current nor previous.

Your circuit should simply repeat G as an output. That was not wanted, but it's essential for the system which is interested in the results.

Your other output, say W, tells if the product of current ABC and previous ABC is divisible with 3.

You need a combinatoric circuit that has output X. X=1 if input ABC is in decimal 0, 3 or 6, otherwise X=0

Store X to a flipflop storage when G drops from 1 to 0. Feed the output of that storage to an OR gate with G. The output of the OR gate is your W.

Comment: since using only one FF, is there a point in trying to reduce the numbers of states?

Comment: Reduce from.. 1 to 0?

Comment: 1 FF = 2 states